# What does this point about triangular number mean

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I was reading about triangular numbers from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

I makes following point on the above web page:

> The number of line segments between closest pairs of dots in the triangle can be represented in terms of the number of dots or with a recurrence relation:
>   $$L_n=3T_{n-1}=3\binom{n}2{}; $$
>   $$L_n=L_{n-1}+3(n-1),L_1=0$$
>   In the limit, the ratio between the two numbers, dots and line segments is 
>   $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T_n}{L_n}=\frac{1}{3}$$

I didn't get anything here, neither what it is indicating with words *"line segments between closest pairs of dots in the triangle"*, nor by those equations. May be I am finding the language uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

They simply refer to what happens when you [triangulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_triangulation) the dots.  Unfortunately, that page doesn't have a diagram, but this is what is meant:

[image]

It can be seen that the number of unit-length line segments is as described in the "triangular number" Wikipedia article, by attaching a unit equilateral triangle to every point except those in the last row.